# Fixed table header changes position/does not align in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table, fixed-header-tables

Here is the scenario. I've a table which populates data on scroll. It contains large number of rows. And on each scroll width of `th` changes dynamically. The table is built with `knockoutjs`. Please find below the structure of `th`.

```
<th data-bind="style: { 'min-width': minWidth + 'px', width: width + '%', height: '25px', 'text-align': 'center' }" style="min-width: 20px; width: 9.30232558139535%; height: 25px; text-align: center;">
    <div class="headerCell" data-bind="click: click" style="width: 136px;">
        <div class="headerText" style="text-align: center;">
            <div class="headerName" data-bind="attr:{title: name}, text: name" title="Name">Name</div>
            <div style="float: right; margin-top: 10PX; MARGIN-right: 1px;" data-bind="css: { 'arrow-up': sortType() == 'Asc', 'arrow-down': sortType() == 'Desc' }" class=""></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</th>
```

The text of `th` is contained within in a `div`. The classes `headerCell` and `headerText` are as below:

```
.headerCell{
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent;
    line-height: 20px;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.headerText{
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    background-color: #333333;
}
```

Now here `th` remains `fixed` but the `th`s does not align with `td` of `tbody`. Sometime it aligns and sometime it does not. This works properly in Firefox. The issue comes in chrome browser.

I tried to fix it with `jquery` plugins as well but none of them worked.

**How do fix the issue of `th` changes it's position when the width of `th` is assigned dynamically?**

Comment: Sticky table headers are really tricky to realize. Read [this](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/09/sticky-table-headers-columns/) tutorial about it. There is a new CSS-Property called `position:sticky;`, but it isn't supported by all browsers. If you want to get a good answer here, you should post a code snippet. Oherwise it is to hard to figure out your problem.

Comment: `position:sticky;` has been discontinued by google - @JanHommes

Comment: That's why I didn't post it as an answer. They showed another solution with jQuery in that tutorial. Did you read it?

Answer (score 1):

I solve sticky headers with a plugin that is a little smarter about handling widths than I am with my custom rolled CSS and HTML.  Datatables is my weapon of choice.

Here's a working demo:  https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/

One hidden benefit -- it's going to be far less markup for the browser (and you) to deal with.  If you go this route and use the HTML table option, don't forget to use properly formatted html tables with `<head>` and `<body>` elements, as Datatables is quite particular.

Comment: I've created the table with knockoutjs and th width changes dynamically in scroll. Is there any  way to resolve in current scenario ???

Comment: Knockout shouldn't throw any barriers.  I've used Datatables with standard HTML, Backbone, Angular, etc.  Here's a basic example from the Datatables site, you'd just have to modify using the fixed header as shown above:  http://datatables.net/dev/knockout/

Comment: To add to that, you might rethink how you handle data.  Rather than loading on scroll is a endless scroll type model, how about doing a "pipeline query" style grab of data, where you get a number, say 25 results, then page them 10 at a time.  That way, you're giving the user a more smooth experience (less loading) but also not overwhelming the get action and slowing things down.  It becomes important to use a method like that as datasets grow to tens of thousands or millions even.  Search and filter features allow you to get around the data in a hurry and get to the point of what they want.

Comment: I tried out with datatable but couldn't achieve the requirement. Data is loaded progressively on scroll in table. I also tried with sDom to wrap table in a div and apply overflow-y:auto and overflow-x:visible to it. But only vertical scroll works, horizontal doesn't work.

Comment: Chako, as a UI developer, I'd STRONGLY recommend avoiding horizontal scroll...it's just not user friendly (AT ALL!)  IF you have too many fields, consider doing show/hide fields to allow users to choose what they see, and initially show them the ones that seem most important.  IT'll be WAY more usable in the long run, regardless of technology.

Comment: you are right but I've to show all the columns all the time with horizontal scroll. If i put horizontal scroll, only tbody scrolls and headers doesn't scroll.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64503/discussion-between-chako-desai-and-bpeterson76).